# How to access `electron.remote.app` in Electron application via DevTools?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc

I want to access `var app = require('electron').remote.app` via DevTools in an Electron Application.

Right now, when I open up DevTools & type in `var app = require('electron').remote.app` I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: Blocked remote.getBuiltin(‘app’)

How do I access the `app` variable via DevTools? I don’t want to access it via code. Is it even possible?

Comment: I could access the app object in the devtools (printing app.isPackaged), using your code, with enabled `nodeIntegration`. I tried electron 6 and also 7.1.9. What version did you use?

Comment: @Rhayene the version is 7.1.8. I still get the error on that app. I have tried as u suggested on a new Hello World app & it worked perfectly fine Not sure what the issue is then

Comment: @Rhayene try it in VSCode. it doesn’t work in that. I guess for packaged apps, it doesn’t work at all I guess

Comment: There is a workaround for a renderer process tho https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20900#issuecomment-549281149. Altho I opened a Github issue so lets see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require('electron').remote.app` cannot be accessed via DevTools for security reasons as said [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21885#issuecomment-578425405) :)